# Finding the height of the binary tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Given the code for finding the height of a binary tree:

```
/*
class Node 
int data;
Node left;
Node right;
*/
int height(Node root)
{
   if(root == null){
   return 0;
}
else{
   int left = height(root.left);
   int right = height(root.right);
   if(left > right){
       return 1 + left;
   }
   else{
       return 1 + right;
   }
 } 
}
```

The example is:

```
     3
   /   \
  5     2
 / \    /
1   4  6
      /
     7
```

and the height is **4** because `3->2->6->7`

I'm having big troubles with understanding the recursion process here. I'd appreciate anyone who explains me the following questions:

**1)** When traversing the tree, do the following two lines **add 1** at each visit of the node? Bigger question: how does it work?

```
 int left = height(root.left);
 int right = height(root.right);
```

2) Do I understand it correctly?:
`int left = height(root.left);` ---> goes until the **leftmost** node ??
`int right = height(root.right);` ---> goes until the **rightmost** node ??

What happens if I had the following tree:

```
     3
   /   \
  5     2
 / \    /
1   4  6
   /  /
  3  7
 /
2
```

and the height would be **5** because of `3->5->4->3->2`?

I'm having difficulties with understanding the recursion of these lines:

```
int left = height(root.left);
int right = height(root.right);
```

My understanding about those lines is `left` goes to the leftmost node while `right` goes to the rightmost node.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger.  This is a very simple function and until you see how the code actually runs, I don't think you can fully understand it.

Comment: You have worked out that if `left` only went to the left most node, that this function wouldn't work, but it does work, so you know this can't possibly be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have a simple algorithm description and you implement it almost literally to obtain the recursive solution. You start from something like:

- a tree with no nodes has height 0
- a tree with any amount of nodes has height 1 + the maximum height between the left subtree and the right subtree

In a recursive algorithm you always have an recursive step (which is the second in this case) and a base case which stops the recursion (tree with no nodes).

So basically height of tree with root 3

```
     3
   /   \
  5     2
 / \    /
1   4  6
      /
     7
```

is 1 + maximum between the height of the two subtrees starting from 3, eg:

```
   5              2
  / \            /
 1   4          6
               /
              7
```

So this is what is done by

```
int left = height(root.left);
int right = height(root.right);
```

Then recursively, height of

```
   5
  / \
 1   4
```

is maximum between height of subtrees

```
 1   4
```

and so on.

Basically at each recursive step you split the execution path into 2 to calculate the height of the subtrees, when both have been calculated you take the greater height, add 1 and return the value.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions specifically:

1) The two lines you have highlighted:

```
int left = height(root.left);
int right = height(root.right);
```

do not add 1 to the height of the tree. Rather, they assign the height of the left sub-tree and the right sub-tree to two separate variables.

The following if-then-else-branch after the assignment is the code that adds 1 to the height:

```
if(left > right) {
    return 1 + left;
} else {
    return 1 + right;
}
```

2) The two recursive calls:

```
int left = height(root.left);
int right = height(root.right);
```

do not exactly go to **just** the leftmost and rightmost nodes of the tree, they visit all the nodes that are the left children of the root node and the right children on the root node. Eventually all the nodes will be visited.

Solving with recursion can often be an elegant approach, but it helps to think of it as solving smaller problems and building the solution up, rather than trying to picture the whole solution in your head.

Let's run through the example you posted.

```
     3
   /   \
  5     2
 / \    /
1   4  6
   /  /
  3  7
 /
2
```

Using recursion, the height would be worked out by first finding out the height of the children below the 2, which is 0.

To find the height of the subtree:

```
2
```

it would add 1 to the height of the subtree below, which is 0, giving us a height of 1.

Then add 1 to the height of the subtree:

```
  3
 /
2
```

Giving us 1 + height of subtree starting at 2 = 2.

This would continue up the subtrees:

```
    4
   /
  3
 /
2
```

1 + height of subtree starting at 3 = 1 + (2) = 3

then:

```
  5
 / \
1   4
   /
  3
 /
2
```

and finally the main tree:

```
     3
   /   \
  5     2
 / \    /
1   4  6
   /  /
  3  7
 /
2
```

The recursive algorithm solves the problem of finding the height of the tree, by finding the height of the smaller subtrees.